# What are the factors that effects the kernel build(Image) to flash on the device?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-source, selinux, android-kernel

I have fully unlocked the Samsung device and I have downloaded the Kernel sources from the [Samsung open-source site](https://opensource.samsung.com/main). I have built the kernel fine with instructions are given in the [README_Kernel.txt](https://github.com/Vatish1/sprint-samsung-s10-5g-kernel/blob/master/README_Kernel.txt) file included in the source code.

I get the build output at `out/arch/arm64/boot/Image`.

I have also downloaded the firmware of the device from [samfrew](https://samfrew.com/model/SM-G977P/): G977PVPU2ASH6

I have extracted the `boot.img` of the downloaded firmware and patched the `Image` using [AIK-Linux-v3.6](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2073775)

When I have flashed(with Odin v3.14) it then it's failed and stuck on Splash Screen(with information about phone status showing on it which I generally see in the download mode.) as following: [image]

This is the first time, I have built a kernel fine and get output. I have fixed the device by flashing the original `boot.img` from the downloaded firmware.

I want to understand why the kernel built from the source code failed to flash. I know a few reasons like:

- The possibility of Samsung doesn't share the full code because of proprietary reasons.
- Wrong toolchain.

How exactly, someone can determine the problem?
Any help/suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Try G977PVPS3BTA1. The other ones are not labeled QQ, and you have Qualcomm chipset, as seen from the model number and the Qualcomm SecureBoot text at the boot screen. The triangle means custom firmware has been loaded and it might need to be restored with Kies.

Shame on me if I am wrong.

[EDIT: Edited "Snapdragon" to "Qualcomm chipset"]

Answer (score 0):

I am adding another answer because this one is completely different than the other one.

I just found out that Qualcomm locks the bootloader ENTIRELY.
So not only OEM unlocking needed, you need to sign your bootloader in a way that Qualcomm Secure Boot does not get in your way.

You still have to use code I posted on my other reply, but, with the addition of signing.

There is an link on explaining how it works:
https://www.timesys.com/security/secure-boot-snapdragon-410/
[Ignore the old Snapdragon, it is the same Qualcomm Secure Boot thing]

Shame on me if I am wrong.

[EDIT: Official documentation!
https://www.qualcomm.com/media/documents/files/secure-boot-and-image-authentication-technical-overview-v2-0.pdf]